# How to call function at the bottom of post using plugin?

Tags: php, plugin-development, filters, hooks, the-content

I am creating a plugin and need to write a function which will invoke at the bottom of posts.

Currently, I have a shortcode created and I'm calling the shortcode at bottom of each post wherever required. I need to add the created shortcode function in the plugin now and invoke from there.

Can anyone suggest me action type to invoke the created function at the bottom of the posts?

Comment: Probably using a hook could be a working thing with the action the post : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post

Answer (score 2):

If you currently are using shortcodes, then most probably you want to display some dynamic content at the bottom of the post. If so, then there is a hook that will allow you to do that: [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content)

If you want to modify the content only when single post is displayed, then you can use this code:

```
function my_the_content_filter( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && get_the_ID() === get_queried_object_id() ) {
        $content .= '<div>Some additional content or whatever you want to be printed in here...</div>';
    }

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_the_content_filter' );
```

If you want to modify it everywhere, then you should change the condition to match your needs.